# Swagger 'swagger.json' loads, but 404 error on swagger UI '{localhost}/swagger' in AspNet project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Working on setting up swagger for a web application hosted with IIS using AspNetCore. The .json page loads and seems to be touching all the API just fine, however when navigating to {localhost}/swagger to view the UI page I receive a 404 error. I have the following code in Startup.cs:

```
//Configure Services


     services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API ", Version = "v1" });
                c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
            });

            }


//Configure
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
                //c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Does anyone see any potential issues with this? Or have any suggestions in terms of troubleshooting? Have been working on this for a while now, hopefully a fresh set of eyes can see something I'm not.

Answer (score 13):

From the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), you set the routePrefix to an empty string if you want the swagger UI to be served at the root of your web app.

> To serve the Swagger UI at the app's root (http://localhost:/), set the RoutePrefix property to an empty string

The default is "/swagger"; it looks like you're overriding this, which is why the UI is not showing at "/swagger." Just hit "localhost:" and the UI should show up.

Remove that assignment of the routePrefix and it should show up at "/swagger" like you expect.

Comment: jbsmith - I commented out the RoutePrefix line. However, now instead of getting the chrome 404 page I am seeing the IIS 404 page (when navigating to {localhost}/swagger). Thoughts?

Comment: @JeremyS. I saw the answer for your question somewhere. You should call _app.UseBaseUrl()_ or _app.UseBasePath()_ for IIS.

Answer (score 10):

Try to use a relative path to SwaggerEndpoint:

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
```

And then navigate to {App Url}/swagger.

Refer to https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/971

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a relative path to SwaggerEndpoint:

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For experiment try adding the next line in your `~\Properties\launchSettings.json` file:

```
"launchUrl": "swagger/index.html"
```

Finally it will be look like this:

[image]

In `Startup.cs` remain `app.UseSwaggerUI` with the next parameters:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
        c.InjectStylesheet("../swagger-ui/custom.css");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to change the following inside the Configure method of the Statrup class.

```
     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
```

To

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

 }
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).