# AspNetCore Swagger for JSON and UI endpoints returning 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I am trying to generate my Swagger documentation as per the [Microsoft Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Using other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043344/swagger-swagger-json-loads-but-404-error-on-swagger-ui-localhost-swagger) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407102/how-to-fix-swagger-json-not-found-in-net-core-2-2-app) has not yielded any progress on the issue...

I'm configuring the swagger gen like so:

```
serviceCollection.AddSwaggerGen(setupAction =>
    {
        setupAction.SwaggerDoc(
            "Open API Specification for Haros v1",
            new OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Title = "Haros API",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "Haros API Description",
                Contact = new OpenApiContact()
                {
                    Email = "myname@domain",
                    Name = "My Name"
                },
                License = new OpenApiLicense()
                {
                    Name = "MIT License"
                }
            });

        setupAction.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
            Scheme = "bearer",
            BearerFormat = "JWT",
            Description = "Attach your bearer token in this format to consume the API: Bearer {token}",
        });

        setupAction.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer",
                    },
                }, new List<string>()
            },
        });
    });
```

And adding the middleware like so:

```
app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(setupAction =>
{
   setupAction.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Haros API v1");
   setupAction.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

Both endpoints (`https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html` and `https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json`) are returning 404.

I've added the option to *GenerateDocumentationFile* to my project and decorated my API controller endpoint with the `///` comments.

What I did notice is that if I comment out the `RoutePrefix` I manage to load this:
[image: Failed to load API definition]

I have followed the Microsoft docs link as close as possible, and I don't see anything I potentially missed. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong or missed?

(additional info: using .NET 5 and loading via Kestrel)

Comment: try this: ``setupAction.RoutePrefix = "swagger";``

Comment: @segmentation_fault open the console view and open the error link in new tab will show you the some detailed error,

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad Changing the `RoutePrefix` to your suggestion yields to the image I attached in my question.
@ZahidMustafa the console doesn't have any useful information except that the request 404'd. Digging into the request doesn't yield any more useful information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured the issue, quite obscure if you ask me. Anyway, [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53521371/7277716) helped me and was basically my issue.

When adding your `SwaggerGen`, the first parameter *name*

```
setupAction.SwaggerDoc(
    "Open API Specification for Haros v1", //... etc
)
```

slots into the URL for the generated documentation at the middleware part here:

```
setupAction.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/<from swagger doc name parameter>/swagger.json", "Haros API v1");
```

If you do this:

```
setupAction.SwaggerDoc(
            "v1", //... etc
)
```

And doing this:

```
setupAction.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Haros API v1");
```

Swagger will load successfully on both endpoints (`https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html` and `https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json`)

Answer (score 0):

Could you chage to SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey?

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "My API",
                    Description = "My API",
                    Contact = new OpenApiContact
                    {
                        Name = "User",
                        Email = string.Empty,
                        Url = new Uri("https://github.com"),
                    }
                });

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "Ex: Bearer {token here}",
                Name = "Authorization",
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference {Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer"}
                    },
                    new string[] { }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Changing to `ApiKey` did not change anything